# Бот дискорд который выдает роли по эмодзи, при запуске пишет ошибку

Tags: python, discord.py

Я написал бот дискорд который выдает роли по эмодзи, но при запуске пишет ошибку
вот код:

```py
import discord
import config

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True


class DiscordBot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Бот {self.user} в сети")

    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, paylood):
        if paylood.message.id == config.ID_POST:
            channel = self.get_channel(paylood.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(paylood.message_id)
            user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=paylood.user_id)
            emoji = str(paylood.emoji)

            try:
                role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLE_LIST(emoji))

                if len([i for i in user.roles if i.id not in config.USER_ROLES_LIST]) <= config.MAX_ROLES:
                    await user.add_roles(role)
                    print(f"{user.name} получил роль {role.name}")
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(paylood.emoji, user)
                    print(f"Ошибка! пользователь {user.name} пытался получить слишком много ролей")

            except Exception as _ex:
                print(repr(_ex))

    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, paylood):
        channel = self.get_channel(paylood.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(paylood.message_id)
        user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=paylood.user_id)

        try:
            emoji = str(paylood.emoji)
            role = discord.utild.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLE_LIST[emoji])
            await user.remove_roles(role)
        except Exception as _ex:
            print(repr(_ex))


client = DiscordBot(intents=intents)
client.run(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

вот config.py

```py
BOT_TOKEN = "тОКЕН"
ID_POST = 0
USER_ROLES_LIST = ()
MAX_ROLES = 3

ROLE_LIST = {
    "✅": 1051595649646338118, #Верифицированый
}
```

вот ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dsrolebot\rolebot.py", line 46, in <module>
    client.run(config.BOT_TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\hadji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\hadji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 746, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 672, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
```

Comment: Скорее всего ответ на ваш вопрос находится [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1464156/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82/1464169#1464169)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо включить Intents на портале разработчиков Discord.
[image: Как показано на скриншоте.]

Comment: Пожалуйста. Не забудьте, что по достижению 100 серверов Intent'ы отключатся и вам будет необходимо пройти проверку.