# Ошибка при запуске бота для Дискорда

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, discord.py

Я написал следующий код, но при его запуске возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/RTS_trading_bot/bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(config["prefix"])
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Как ее решить? Код бота:

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

file = open("config.json", "r")
config = json.load(file)

bot = commands.Bot(config["prefix"])

@bot.command(name="ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}pong')


bot.run(config["token"])
```

Код файла конфигурации .json:

```
{
  "token": "MTA1NjMwNDcwNDk3MzQzOTA0Nw.Gi0k4_.cZhgBhImQL2J1-GDYQYs5FrPCsNL2ZLUMSAW1U",
  "prefix": "/"
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо включить Intents.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

И так же на сайте https://discord.com/developers/applications включить все Intents для бота.
Я уже раннее отвечал на такой вопрос:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476819/533270