# Discord бот не отвечает на серверах

Tags: python, discord

Код:

```
import openai
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

openai.api_key = "ключик"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.command()
async def chat(ctx, *, message):
    if ctx.guild is None:
        await ctx.send("This command can only be used on a server.")
        return

    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=f"User: {message}",
        max_tokens=2048,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )

    await ctx.send(f'ChatGPT: {response.choices[0].text}')

bot.run('токен')
```

пытался решить проблему чекая разрешения и настройки, но не разобрался. Стоит разрешение отправлять сообщения, закинул на сервер, но отвечает только в лс

скрин консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бот не работает т.к. у Вашего бота не включены `Intents`.
Я отвечал на данный вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476679/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83/1476819#1476819).

После включения измените строку:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

На:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько возможных причин, по которым ваш бот может не отвечать на серверах:

1. Неправильный токен. Убедитесь, что вы используете правильный токен
   для своего бота. Если вы повторно создали токен, вам нужно будет
   обновить код с помощью нового токена.
2. Бот не добавлен на сервер: бот должен быть добавлен на сервер,
   прежде чем он сможет отвечать на команды. Убедитесь, что бот
   добавлен на сервер и имеет необходимые разрешения.
3. Бот не в сети. Убедитесь, что бот подключен к сети и работает на
   вашем устройстве. Если вы запускаете бота локально, убедитесь, что
   ваше интернет-соединение стабильно и что ваше устройство не
   находится в спящем режиме.
4. Неверный префикс команды: убедитесь, что вы используете правильный
   префикс команды при попытке вызвать бота. Префикс задается при
   создании бота, по умолчанию «/».
5. Бот ограничен по скорости: Discord накладывает ограничение на
   скорость для всех запросов API, включая команды бота. Если ваш бот
   делает слишком много запросов слишком быстро, его скорость может
   быть ограничена.
6. Бот заблокирован Discord: если ваш бот заблокирован Discord,
   проверьте, не нарушает ли ваш бот условия обслуживания Discord.
7. Бот может работать со сбоями из-за ошибки в коде, обязательно
   проверьте свой код на наличие ошибок и исправьте их
8. Бот заблокирован владельцем или администратором сервера, уточните у
   них заблокирован бот или нет
9. Если бот работает на твоём пк попробуй на хостинг кинуть вот 1 хост: [Replit](https://Replit.com/)

Попробуйте выполнить эти шаги, и если у вас все еще есть проблемы, предоставьте дополнительную информацию о проблеме и сообщениях об ошибках, если таковые имеются, которые вы получаете.

Comment: бот в сети и отвечает но на сервере не видит команд. а так все хорошо

Comment: [Вот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73458847/discord-py-error-message-discord-ext-commands-bot-privileged-message-content-i)

Answer (score 0):

На сайте - https://discord.com/developers/applications

В разделе Bot

Включите следующие пункты:
PRESENCE INTENT
SERVER MEMBERS INTENT
MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT