# Пытаюсь создать бота на пайтон для дискорда

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```python
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

file = open('config.json', 'r')
config = json.load(file)

bot = commands.Bot(config['prefix'])

@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping (ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}pong')
    
    
    
bot.run(config['token'])
```

Выдает такую ошибку:
" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\DISCORD_BOT\main.py", line 8, in 
bot = commands.Bot(config['prefix'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BotBase.**init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents' "

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо добавить в строку `intents`:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'], intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Так же включить `Intents` на сайте. Пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476679/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83/1476819#1476819).