# Ошибка Exception has occurred: TypeError при запуске дискорд бота (python)

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

При запуске дискорд бота вылезает ошибка `Exception has occurred: TypeError BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'.`

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
from discord import app_commands
from config_file import settings

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Loading...')
    print('Client is loaded. Please enter password for autorization and launch bot: ')
    print(f'Welcome {client.user}! Bot had launched')
    print("""Aviable commands (temporaly disabled): 
        /meslog - display of messages from users
        /stats - display all settings and statics about bot""")
```

Пробовал делать вот так, но ошибка никуда не пропала:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
from discord import app_commands
from config_file import settings

bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default()), commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
    print('Loading...')
    print('Client is loaded. Please enter password for autorization and launch bot: ')
    print(f'Welcome {client.user}! Bot had launched')
    print("""Aviable commands (temporaly disabled): 
        /meslog - display of messages from users
        /stats - display all settings and statics about bot""")
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+missing+1+required+keyword-only+argument%3A+%27intents%27)

Comment: Благодарю, все починилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените строку:

```
bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default()), commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
```

На эту:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Так же включить `Intents` на сайте. Пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476679/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83/1476819#1476819).