# Почему бот в дискорд не отправляет сообщения на сервер?

Tags: python, бот, discord

Почему бот в дискорд не отправляет сообщения на сервер?

Вот код:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$',intents = discord.Intents.default())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот включился")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("Привет"):
        await message.channel.send("И тебе привет!")


bot.run('токен')
```

Comment: на канал точнее

Comment: а нам от куда знать? где ошибка?

Comment: ГЕНИАЛЬНО я на то и спрашиваю где я что сделал не так

Answer (score 0):

Ваш бот не видит текст сообщений, соответственно не обрабатывает команду. Вам необходимо включить Intents на портале разработчиков Discord. Пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476679/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83/1476819#1476819).

И либо просто разрешить принимать `message_content`:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$',intents = intents)
```

Либо разрешить все `Intents`, но это будет работать лишь до 100 серверов в боте:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$',intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

Comment: Вааай родной от души благодарю