# Пустое свойство Content

Tags: c#, discord

Изучаю разработку дискорд-ботов с использованием библиотеки Discord.Net

Почему-то когда я отсылаю сообщение, бот его обрабатывает, но получить его содержимое не может:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом все пункты в Indents у меня включены:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
private Task Client_MessageReceived(SocketMessage msg)
{
  if (msg.Author.IsBot) return Task.CompletedTask;

  msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync(msg.Content);

  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: [Комментарий читайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1460497/220553)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, это решило проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В точке входа программы, или где у вас создаётся новый экземпляр DiscordSocketClient для дальнейшего использования, добавьте в конструктор DiscordSocketConfig с разрешёнными GatewayIntents.

Выглядеть должно так:

Было:

```
var Client = new DiscordSocketClient();
await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, Params.Token);
await Client.StartAsync();
```

Стало:

```
var Client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
{
     GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All
});
await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, Params.Token);
await Client.StartAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Вы не включили `Intents` на портале разработчиков Discord.

Пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476679/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83/1476819#1476819).

Comment: Все три пункта у меня включены

Comment: В таком случае попробуйте этот способ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935914/cant-get-any-discord-messages-from-users/73937627#73937627

Comment: Я не писал на c#. По этому не знаю как решить проблему