# я хз что делать всё настроил не работает DISCORD BOT

Tags: python

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


async def draw(ctx, width: int = 500, height: int = 500, color: str = 'white'):

    img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color)


    paint = ImageDraw.Draw(img)


    for i in range(random.randint(10, 20)):
        x1, y1 = random.randint(0, width), random.randint(0, height)
        x2, y2 = random.randint(0, width), random.randint(0, height)
        paint.line((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill='black', width=3)

    buffer = BytesIO()
    img.save(buffer, format='PNG')
    buffer.seek(0)

    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(buffer, filename='drawing.png'))

client.run('тут мой токен')
```

ошибка:

````
    client.run('MTA5MjUzMDg2NjY3NDIwODc4OQ.GTlIhj.UEFxov_gNvbUkugmpg2eaAOFx-dskw4Y8hnFog')
  File "D:\Projects\Paint\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "D:\Python\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "D:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Projects\Paint\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "D:\Projects\Paint\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 778, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "D:\Projects\Paint\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 704, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.```
````

Comment: Ставлю тревогу "дубликат", так как даже со стороны видно, что вопросы одинаковые. Ну и `@qrts` говорит тоже самое ("уже отвечал на этот вопрос")

Comment: за такую формулировку вопроса - сразу минус.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключается в **Intents**. Вам нужно переключить ползунок **message content** на официальном сайте **Discord Developers**.

Я отвечал на данный вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476679/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83/1476819#1476819).