# Ошибка при запуске discord.py помогите

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: Ошибка]

При запуске :

> `__init__()` missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Код:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
```

Как пофиксить???

Comment: [Возможный дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1464156/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82/1464169#1464169)

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых код не может состоять из одной строки

А во вторых вы забыли указать параметр intents

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Бот запущен')

bot.run('token')
```